# How to load google maps after page loads in angularjs (to improve performance)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have an angularJS webapp that is using google maps. For performance purposes I would like to prioritise the page load or at least the critical rendering path, so I would like to delay the load of google maps after page loads.

To get a little bit more in detail, actually I have the script that loads google maps in the index page, like:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- My code here -->
<script async defer type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.37"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I have a partial template view that has a directive that is using google maps.

```
<boats-map location="Spain" zoom="8" class="map-container"></boats-map>
```

I think the detail of the directive is not relevant for the issue. But should be something like:

```
.directive('boatsMap',  [
    function() {            

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {  

        console.log("Map loaded");                                                            
        // Do whatever logic
    }
```

Everything is working, as said this is only for performance purposes, but what I have noticed in the network waterfall of devtools is that when I comment the script that loads google maps and also the directive in my view, my page and critical rendering path loads around 3 seconds earlier.

So, I would like to delay this functionality until the page completely loads.

Please note the script is using async and defer to asynchronous load the script, but this not avoid the big impact in the load.

I have read approaches like this: [How do I load google maps external javascript after page loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354358/how-do-i-load-google-maps-external-javascript-after-page-loads/24684234) but not sure if this is the angular way.

Please find screenshot of performance:
1. With google maps script:
[image]

2. Commenting the google maps script:
   [image]

Comment: There is no point in putting `$(document).ready` inside an AngularJS directive. The $compile service never links a directive before the DOMcontentLoaded event.

Comment: Thanks. Edited. But, any answer to go to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One option to consider would be to utilize the `callback` parameter in conjunction with `async` attribute. This way you could guarantee Google Maps API is loaded, from [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#sync):

> When the API is ready, it will call the function specified using the
>   `callback` parameter.

The list of changes:

a) specify `callback` function name:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?callback=lazyLoadCallback"></script>
```

b) initialize map once Google Maps API is ready:

```
link: function(scope) {
    window.lazyLoadCallback = () => {
       //Google Maps API is ready...        
    };
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jUEAgbjk7Ure8YQVmFjt?p=preview)